# rspec-rails generator doesn't create spec/rails_helper.rb

Tags: rspec-rails

I created new Rails app, then added gem 'rspec-rails' to Gemfile, bundle install-ed, and launched

```
rails g rspec:install
  create  .rspec   
  create  spec
  create  spec/spec_helper.rb
```

Why it didn't create spec/rails_helper.rb ?

My Gemfile is being generated with new Rails aplication with empty lines and comments removed. I only added the last line to it.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
gem 'rspec-rails'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rails_helper.rb` is new to Rspec Rails 3.x. You may be running an earlier version. Check your `Gemfile.lock` or run `bundle list | grep rspec-rails` to see which version you're running.

Comment: yep, I see rspec-rails (2.14.1) I'll try 3.x tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because it needs to be in both :development and :test
It should be:

group :development, :test do
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 6.0.0'
end